# Google Cloud Composer "Error: Server Error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-airflow

My Google Cloud Composer is not working since yesterday.

I can't access the airflow interface, returning:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

A warning is showed in Google Cloud Compose Console:

```
UPDATE operation on this environment failed 9 hours ago with the following error message:
Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: TP_DEPLOYMENT_UPDATING
response_timestamp {
  seconds: 1578617359
  nanos: 100000000
}
debug_info: "Deployment Manager experimental endpoint enabled"
].
```

There's no support in chat to Composer.

Answer (score 0):

Did someone in your project recently try to update the Composer environment (e.g., install a new pypi package)? I think [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) article could be useful in this case, and also [this](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/28/airflow-on-kubernetes-part-1-a-different-kind-of-operator/) one.

Composer has some undeclared dependencies and if they conflict with your pypi packages, this error will come up. The current workaround is to use either a virtualenvoperator or a kubernetes pod operator, so you never actually install your packages in the composer environment.

Also, Airflow web server logs are available in Stackdriver logging - it'll be useful to include them into your question with versions of Composer and Airflow.

**EDIT** You can try to upgrade (is a beta feature) your environment to the latest version following this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading).